# Different outputs from recursive functions

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I just found out about *recursive functions* about a few minutes back. I was playing around with them and now I am getting different outputs from the following functions:

```
int function(int m)   {
    m = 2*m;
    std::cout<<"In f m = "<<m<<std::endl;
    if(m > 20)
    {
        return m;
    }
    function(m);
};

int function2(int n)   {
    n = 2*n;
    std::cout<<"In f2 n = "<<n<<std::endl;
    if(n < 20)
    {
        function2(n);
    }
    return n;
};

int main()  {
    int a = 2;
    std::cout <<"function(a) = "<<function(a)<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"function2(a) = "<<function2(a);
    return 1;
}
```

To this I get the output:

> In f m = 4
>   In f m = 8
>   In f m = 16
>   In f m = 32
>   function(a) = 32
>   In f2 n = 4
>   In f2 n = 8
>   In f2 n = 16
>   In f2 n = 32
>   function2(a) = 4

Shouldn't they both yield result of `32`?

Comment: Your first function is actually exhibiting undefined behavior because it is not returning a value if the base case isn't triggered.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia What do u mean by 'base case' here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only do `return n` and don't assign it from the recursive calls, so it will for the first call always be `4`.

You should to e.g.

```
if(n < 20)
    n = function2(n);
return n;
```

Comment: That fixed it! Don't know why I didn't notice that.

Comment: I should have noticed that n is local to every function call.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in function2，whether n less than or greater than 20 or not,statement `return n` will
always be executed as the if statement will not return.so when you pass the argument a=2 in function2, it will return 4.If u want both of them to return the same result.
u can modify function2 like

```
if(n < 20)
{
    function2(n);
}
else
    return n;
```